# Error Loading Model Table in Controller

Tags: php, model, frameworks, composer-php

Currently I develop a small house framework, and I encounter some small problems with namespaces, when I want to load a Model, the page will look for the Table file in the Controller, despite the use of namespaces.

My Architecture:

```
/app/
    /Controllers/
    /View/
    /Model/
        /Table/
        /Entity/
/config/
/src/
/Config/
    Config.php
/Controller/
    Controller.php
/Database/
    Database.php
/Network/
    Request.php
Application.php
/vendor/
    /composer/
    autoload.php
composer.json
index.php
```

The code of the pages linked to the controller below, I think the problem come to compose but not on ...

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "damien/framework",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Damien aaa",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

**PostsController.php (app/Controller)**

```
namespace App\Controller;


use App\Table\PostsTable;

class PostsController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
       $table = new PostsTable();
    }
}
```

**PostsTable.php (app/Model/Table)**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

class PostsTable {

}
```

**Controller.php (src/Controller)**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Application;
use App\Network\Request;

class Controller extends Application {
    protected $viewPath = ROOT . VIEW;
    protected $template = ROOT . TEMPLATE;
    protected $layout = "default";
    public $request;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->render($this->request->controller().'/'. $this->request->action());
    }



    /*
     * $template String Renvoie le layout demander, si celui-ci existe
     */
    public function layout($template) {
        if($template != $this->layout) {
            require $this->template . $template . '.php';
        }
    }

    /*
     * $view string Renvoie la vue correspondant au controller et à la vue demander
     * $params string Permet de transmettre des variables à la vue
     */
    public function render($view, $params = []) {
        extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
        ob_start();
        if($view != null) {
            require $this->viewPath . '/' . str_replace('.', '/', $view) . '.php';
        } else {
            require $this->viewPath . '/' . $this->request->controller() . '/' . $this->request->action() . '.php';
        }
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        require $this->template .$this->layout . '.php';
    }

}
```

On these codes above, I call the Table Posts from the controller, when I make a new PostsTable, error.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Table\PostsTable' not found in D:\Sites\Dev\Framework\app\Controller\PostsController.php on line 10
>       ( ! ) Error: Class 'Table\PostsTable' not found in D:\Sites\Dev\Framework\app\Controller\PostsController.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your composer configuration is wrong.

This following line define the namespace App in the folder src:
`"App\\": "src"`

change it to: `"App\\": "app"` and update composer

EDIT: you also use the wrong namespace for the model:

`use App\Table\PostsTable;`

and later:
PostsTable.php (app/Model/Table)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now I have a new error, it no longer finds the controller
    
    
Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\Controller' not found in D:\Sites\Dev\Framework\app\Controller\PostsController.php on line 4

Comment: Is your folder really called "Controller**s**", because your namespace is without the last letter. Its confusing me

Comment: Yes the name is well Controller in the "s" at the end.

Comment: then the namespace must use the "s" at the end too.

Comment: Thanks google ... translation problem of my previous post.
My classes are in the singular (without s) see image below)

http://prntscr.com/du5pxt

Comment: Oh your main controller is in the src folder. That means, that you need a second Namespace for the src folder.

Comment: Basically, I would need a namespace for controllers and another for models? (If I understood correctly)
Is it not possible to do otherwise?
And by composing + a autoloader? For the moment I did not find it useful to

In fact, a few days ago I had created an AppController in app / Controller but I remember that it does not load properly (class not found)

Comment: You have the folder "app" and the folder "src". Use for 2 different folder 2 different namespaces. for the Models you can use the Namespace too. Example: App\Model\Table\PostsTable, Src\Controller\Controller.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this solution, Thanks